# Check if a sublist contains an item

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in Python. As illustrated below, I want to check if one of the sublists contains an item. The following attempt fails. Does anyone know of a simple way -- without me writing my own for loop?

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9]
>>> 2 in a
```

I was hoping for `True` but the return was `False`

Comment: This is a variation on the question of how to [flatten a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an item is in a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514139/check-if-an-item-is-in-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9]
>>> any(2 in i for i in a)
True
```

Comment: `any(8 in i for i in a)` -> `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Answer (score 4):

For a list that contains some lists and some integers, you need to test whether the element `i` is a list before testing whether the search target is in `i`.

```py
>>> any(2 in i for i in a if isinstance(i, list))
True
>>> any(8 in i for i in a if isinstance(i, list))
False
```

If you don't check whether `i` is a list, then you'll get an error like below. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13730677/4518341) is wrong, because it gives this error.

```py
>>> any(8 in i for i in a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    any(8 in i for i in a)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <genexpr>
    any(8 in i for i in a)
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this type of situation is where we can take some inspiration from functional programming by delegating the evaluation of the boolean expression to its own function. This way, if you need to change the behaviour of your bool condition, you only need to change that function definition!

Let's say you want to check sublists AND also `int` that happen to be in the top level. We can define a function that returns a boolean when performing a comparison on a single list element:

```
def elem(a, b):
    '''
    Defines if an object b matches a.
    '''

    return (isinstance(b, int) and a == b) or (isinstance(b, list) and a in b)
```

Note here that this function says nothing about our list - the argument `b` in our usage is just a single element within the list, but we could just as easily call it just to compare two values. Now we have the following:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9]

>>> any(elem(2, i) for i in a)
True

>>> any(elem(8, i) for i in a)
True

>>> any(elem(10, i) for i in a)
False
```

Bingo! Another benefit of this type of definition is that it allows you to partially apply functions, and gives you the ability to assign names to searches for only one type of number:

```
from functools import partial

>>> contains2 = partial(elem, 2)

>>> any(map(contains2, a))
True

>>> b = [[1],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9]]
>>> any(map(contains2, b))
False
```

In my opinion, this makes for more readable code at the cost of a bit of boilerplate and the need to know what `map` does - since you can make your variable names sensical rather than a jungle of temporary list comprehension variables. I don't particularly care if the functional approach is less Pythonic - Python is a multiparadigm language and I think it looks better this way, plain and simple. But that's personal choice - it's up to you.

Now let's say that our situation has changed and we now want to check only the sublists - it's not enough for an occurrence in a top level. That's okay because now all we need to change is our definition of `elem`. Let's see:

```
def elem(a, b):
    return isinstance(b, list) and a in b
```

We've just removed the possibility of a match in the case that `b` is a top level int! If we run this now:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9,"a",["b","c"]]
>>> any(elem(2, i) for i in a)
True
>>> any(elem(8, i) for i in a)
False
```

I'll illustrate one final example that really drives home how powerful this type of definition is. Suppose we have a list of arbitrarily deeply nested lists of integers. How do we check if an integer is in any of the levels?

We can take a recursive approach - and it doesn't take much modification at all:

```
def elem(a, b):
    return (isinstance(b, int) and a == b) or \
           (isinstance(b, list) and any(map(partial(elem, a), b)))
```

Because we've used this recursive definition that is defined to act on a single element, all the previous lines of code used still work:

```
>>> d = [1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]]
>>> any(elem(1, i) for i in d)
True
>>> any(elem(4, i) for i in d)
True
>>> any(elem(10, i) for i in d)
False
>>> any(map(contains2, d))
True
```

Of course, given that this function is now recursive, we can really just call it directly:

```
>>> elem(4, d)
True
```

But the point remains that this modular approach has allowed us to alter the functionality by only changing the definition of `elem` without touching our main script, which means less TypeErrors and quicker refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any way of doing the test without a loop of some kind.

Here's a function that uses a straightforward `for` loop to explicitly check for an object within a sublist:

```
def sublist_contains(lst, obj):
    for item in lst:
        try:
            if obj in item:
                return True
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return False
```

Of course, that doesn't test if the object is in the top level list, nor will it work if there is more than one level of nesting. Here's a more general solution using recursion, which puts the loop in a generator expression that's passed to the built-in function `any`:

```
def nested_contains(lst, obj):
    return any(item == obj or
               isinstance(item, list) and nested_contains(item, obj)
               for item in lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to do this is:

```
  a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],7,8,9]
  result = [2 in i for i in a]

  True in result --> True
```

Comment: `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`