# Check if an item is in a nested list

Tags: python, list

in a simple list following check is trivial:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

2 in x  -> True
```

but if it is a list of list, such as:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

2 in x   -> False
```

how can this be addressed in order to return `True`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this, using the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function. It's the most idiomatic solution, and it's also efficient, because `any` short-circuits and stops as soon as it finds the first match:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
any(2 in sl for sl in x)
=> True
```

Comment: what is sl in this case?

Comment: Just a variable name, it stands for "sub-list"

Comment: Your solution wasn't exactly what I needed but it gave enough info for me to figure out my problem. I posted the solution to my problem. It prints out nested elements that aren't in another nested list.

Comment: I was able to use `any()` for dicts nested inside a list. Thanks +1

Answer (score 10):

Here's a recursive version that works for any level of nesting.

```
def in_nested_list(my_list, item):
    """
    Determines if an item is in my_list, even if nested in a lower-level list.
    """
    if item in my_list:
        return True
    else:
        return any(in_nested_list(sublist, item) for sublist in my_list if isinstance(sublist, list))
```

Here are a few tests:

```
x = [1, 3, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, [], [2, 3, 'a']]]
print in_nested_list(x, 2)
print in_nested_list(x, 5)
print in_nested_list(x, 'a')
print in_nested_list(x, 'b')
print in_nested_list(x, [])
print in_nested_list(x, [1, 2])
print in_nested_list(x, [1, 2, 3])

True
False
True
False
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set.issubset()` and `itertools.chain()`:

```
In [55]: x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

In [56]: {4}.issubset(chain.from_iterable(x))
Out[56]: True

In [57]: {10}.issubset(chain.from_iterable(x))
Out[57]: False
```

You can also chek the membership for multiple items efficiently:

```
In [70]: {2, 4}.issubset(chain.from_iterable(x))
Out[70]: True

In [71]: {2, 4, 10}.issubset(chain.from_iterable(x))
Out[71]: False
```

Comment: Why not just `4 in chain.from_iterable(x)`, and avoid the `set` for the single element test case? `in` works on arbitrary iterables after all, and short-circuits just fine, without requiring hashable elements. Up-voted regardless (`chain` is a good solution).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sure, if it's a one shot (few) operation there's no need to convert to set. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
for arr in x:
    if 2 in arr:
        print True
        break
```

I would recommend Oscar's answer as `any` is the right option here.

Comment: This won't work unless the element happens to be in the last sublist... and besides, it should short-circuit in case the element is found earlier. And that's what `any` is required here, see my answer.

Comment: Just tested and it works then as well, even if it's not in last sublist.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Test it with `x = [[3,3], [4,4]]` and it will work, even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
x = [0, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, [4, 5, [6], []], [7, 8]]]
def find_n(input_list, n):
    for el in input_list:
        if el == n or (isinstance(el, list) and find_n(el, n)):
            return True
    return False
print(find_n(x, 6))
```

Note that, somewhat interestingly:

```
def find_n(input_list, n):
    return any([el == n or (isinstance(el, list) and find_n(el, n)) for el in input_list])
return (find_n(x, 6))
```

Is over 50% slower to execute.

**Original Answer(s)**

What if you have a depth greater than 2? Here's one approach to the generic case:

```
x = [0, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, [4, 5, [6], []], [7, 8]]]

def flatten(input_list):
    flat_list = []
    for sublist_or_el in input_list:
        if isinstance(sublist_or_el, list):
            for sublist_or_el2 in flatten(sublist_or_el):
                flat_list.append(sublist_or_el2)
        else:
            flat_list.append(sublist_or_el)
    return flat_list

print(6 in flatten(x))
```

Not sure about speed though, but as I said, it's one approach that may be useful to someone!

**EDIT - BETTER (FASTER) ANSWER:**

This reduces the time taken (if `n` is found, actually even if it is not found, about half the time actually...) by returning early. This is slightly faster than @Curt F.'s answer, and slower than creating a function that assumes a maximum depth of 2 (the accepted answer).

```
x = [0, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, [4, 5, [6], []], [7, 8]]]
def find_n(input_list, n):
    flat_list = []
    for sublist_or_el in input_list:
        if isinstance(sublist_or_el, list):
            if find_n(sublist_or_el, n) == True:
                return True
        elif sublist_or_el == n:
            return True
    return False
print(find_n(x, 6))
```

---

Quick timing (very hacky, sorry, busy today!):

```
import time

x = [0, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, [4, 5, [6], []], [7, 8]]]

def a():
    def flatten(input_list):
        flat_list = []
        for sublist_or_el in input_list:
            if isinstance(sublist_or_el, list):
                for sublist_or_el2 in flatten(sublist_or_el):
                    flat_list.append(sublist_or_el2)
            else:
                flat_list.append(sublist_or_el)
        return flat_list
    return (6 in flatten(x))

def b():
    def find_n(input_list, n):
        flat_list = []
        for sublist_or_el in input_list:
            if isinstance(sublist_or_el, list):
                if find_n(sublist_or_el, n) == True:
                    return True
            elif sublist_or_el == n:
                return True
        return False
    return (find_n(x, 6))


zz = 0
for i in range(100000):
    start_time = time.clock()
    res = a()
    zz += time.clock() - start_time
print(a())
print((zz)/100, "seconds")

zz = 0
for i in range(100000):
    start_time = time.clock()
    res = b()
    zz += time.clock() - start_time
print(b())
print((zz)/100, "seconds")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Óscar Lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201359/%C3%93scar-l%C3%B3pez) answer is so great! I recommend to use it.

However, you can use *itertools* to flatten the list and eval it, so:

```
import itertools

x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
2 in itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)

Output: True
```

Also, you can make it "manually" through comprehension:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
2 in [item for sub_list in x for item in sub_list]

Output: True
```

These're only other ways to make it, good luck.

Comment: if I have float elements in list I get TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable

Comment: Hi @Khaned!, this error "numpy.float32" seems like you want to iterate a float values instead of an iterable object. So, also look like you have a list of numpy.float32... check what is iterating you

Comment: I have a list of numpy.float32, how can I iterate it?

Comment: But, is your list of numpy.float32 "[numpy.float32(a), numpy.float32(b),...]"? or is a list with lists of numpy.float32 "[[numpy.float32(a), numpy.float32(b),...], [numpy.float32(a), numpy.float32(b),...], ...]"? 

because my code example apply for the second type (a list with list of items, in this case numpy.float)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 2 in [i for sublist in x  for i in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is based on Óscar López's solution. His solution wasn't exactly what I needed for my problem but it gave enough info for me to figure out my problem. So if you have nested elements in one list and need to see if they're in another nested list, this would work.

```
#!python2

lst1 = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['d', '4'], ['e', '5']]
lst2 = [['b', '2'], ['d', '4'], ['f', '6'], ['h', '8'], ['j', '10'], ['l', '12'], ['n', '14']]

# comparing by index 0, prints lst1 items that aren't in lst2
for i in lst1:
    if not any(i[0] in sublst for sublst in lst2):
        print i
'''
['a', '1']
['c', '3']
['e', '5']
'''

print

# comparing by index 0, prints lst2 items that aren't in lst1
for i in lst2:
    if not any(i[0] in sublst for sublst in lst1):
        print i
'''
['f', '6']
['h', '8']
['j', '10']
['l', '12']
['n', '14']
'''
```