# Searching a nested list with recursion

Tags: python

I want to check if a certain number exists in a nested list

```
Slist = [[[10, 20], [30, 40]], [[50, 60], [70, 80]]]

def ASearch(t, L):

if t==L:
    return True
else:

    return  ASearch(t, L[0]) or ASearch(t, L[1])

ASearch(15,Slist)
```

What is the problem?

**Update:**

The OP meant to post this:

```
Slist = [[[10, 20], [30, 40]], [[50, 60], [70, 80]]]

def ASearch(t, L):

    if t==L:
        return True
    return ASearch(t, L[0]) or ASearch(t, L[1])


print(ASearch(15, Slist))
print(ASearch(50, Slist))
```

Expected output:

```
False
True
```

Actual output:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: 15 is not in the list so it will never return True? Your indentation is wrong?

Comment: @AK47 Doesn't work regardless

Comment: Can 2 'or'd values ever evaluate to 15? Will it always turn x or y as a True/False?

Comment: I think the [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514139/check-if-an-item-is-in-a-nested-list) will do what you want. Using the any keyword also has the advantage of working with lists of any length, rather than explicitly slicing the list like you do above.

Comment: @user8956966: Please make sure you post with correct indentation. If  that is the identical indentation you used in your code then please also fix it in your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the few problems in your code is that it can only return `True`.

What you want is probably this:

```
def ASearch(t, L):
    if type(L) == list:
        return any(ASearch(t, l) for l in L)
    else:
        return t == L
```

Comment: [Comment deleted because it was wrong and misleading.]

Comment: @mrCarnivore example?

Comment: I must take back my comment after trying it out myself. It does indeed work. Apparently I overlooked the nested call to ASearch!

Comment: @mrCarnivore You can always delete your comment completely. Next to your name and comment timestamp, there is a subtle delete button :-)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: I know. But then the other users comment does not make any sense any more. And I did not want to cause an avalanche. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be flattening the list separately and then checking if the element is included in the flattened list:

```
def flatten(L):
    flat = []
    if isinstance(L, list):
        for item in L:
            flat += flatten(item)
    else:
        flat.append(L)
    return flat


def ASearch(t, L):
    return t in flatten(L)
```

You can now call your `ASearch` function using the element and the list: `ASearch(50, nested_list)`.

Alternatively, you can make `ASearch` a lambda-function now:

```
ASearch = lambda t,L: t in flatten(L)
```