# how to test if an integer is in a sub-list in a list

Tags: python

I'd like to test if 3 is the first number of the element (an integer or the first of a sub-list) like this :

```
lst=[2, [3,6], [4,1,7]]
3 in lst
```

The result should be True because 3 is the first element of [3,6].

Btw: my dataset won't make my list like [3, [3,7]] (alone and in a sublist)

Comment: You should show what you've attempted yourself.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you fail? Additionally, do not call your variables like builtin types (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`, ...).

Comment: also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728023/python-2-7-check-if-a-sublist-contains-an-item

Comment: Do you ask **how to make this works**, or **oh, I thought that would work**? The earlier results in the previous comments, while the later states you actually didn't understand what the `in` operator does.

Comment: Could your data ever have a sub-sub-list?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pretty simple recursive function like:

```
l =[2, [3,6], [4,1,7]]

def inList(l, n):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return l[0] == n or any(inList(member, n) for member in l[1:])
    else:
        return False

inList(l, 3) # True
inList(l, 9) # False
inList(l, 2) # True
```

This has the advantage of digging into deeply nested lists too:

```
l =[2, [3,6], [4,1,[9,[5]], 7]]
inList(l, 5) # True
```

Comment: OP only wants it to return `True` if n matches the first element of any of the lists, not any element

Comment: Thanks @Dan, when will I learn that reading comprehension is broken before coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no sub-sub-lists:

```
l=[2, [3,6], [4,1,7]]
first_elements = [i[0] if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in l]  # [2, 3, 4]
print(3 in first_elements)
```

Output:

`True`

Comment: This is nice, but problematic with a list like `l=[2, [3,6], [4,1,7], 5]`. `print(5 in first_elements)` => True.

Comment: @MarkMeyer from reading the question, I would say that `l=[2, [3,6], [4,1,7], 5]` should still return True, although, it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the List, and check if sub-elements `sub` is a list or an integer, and return your desired result :

```
L = [2, [3,6], [4,1,7]]
num = 2
res = False
for sub in L:
    if isinstance(sub, list):
        if num in sub:
            res = True
            break
    else:
        if num == sub:
            res = True

print(res)
```