# Get the index of the sublist when checking for the existence of an element

Tags: python

As a continuation for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728023/check-if-a-sublist-contains-an-item), how can I get the index of the sublist which contains the element?

So for example if I have:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
any(2 in i for i in a)
....
```

How can I get 0 as a result (Because a[0] contains the number 2)?

Comment: `next(i for i, el in enumerate(a) if 2 in el)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Great! But what if I have the same value (e.g 2) in multiple sublists? This solution gives only the first occurrence it seems.

Comment: Then use list comprehension: `[i for i, el in enumerate(a) if 2 in el]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which iterates over list with indexes using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will do the trick:

```py
res = [i for i, el in enumerate(a) if 2 in el]
```

You can achieve same using regular [*for*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop:

```py
res = []
for i, el in enumerate(a):
    if 2 in el:
        res.append(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this too:

```py
for idx, sublst in enumerate(a):
    if 2 in sublst: 
        print(idx)
```

Output:

```
0
```