# How to check if an element is in a list-of-lists at a certain index in the sub-list?

Tags: python

Is it possible to check if something is in a list of lists at a specific index? Example:

```
l_list = [['a', 2, True], ['b', 1, False], ['c', 5, True], ...]
if 'a' in l_list:
    print('Yes')
```

I want to check if 'a' exists inside of `l_list` (and just ignore other values) as any of the sub-lists ***first value*** without iterating over the whole list.

Comment: If the thing you are looking for is always the first thing in the sublist you could use: `if 'a' in (first for first, *rest in l_list):`, but you need to look at the sublists up to the point where you find (or don't find) a match.

Comment: Anything you do here is going to be morally equivalent to a loop. The real best answer for how to accomplish what you want depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish and the real structure of your data.

Comment: `'a'` is NOT in `l_list`. It is inside a list that is a an entry in `l_list`. What do you want to check?

Comment: @balderman they are trying to check `any(('a' in l for l in l_list))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a sublist contains an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728023/check-if-a-sublist-contains-an-item)

Comment: @NickS1 In that question, the top-level list contains non-lists, and OP doesn't specify that the element must be at a certain position.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, I should've read with more attention! But now I see the difference! Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over the first elements:

```
>>> 'a' in [item[0] for item in l_list]
True
```

but that's still `O(n)`

Comment: If you make this a generator rather than a list, you can at least exit early if the match is found: `(item[0] for item in l_list)`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the sublists (`for sub in l_list`), access the first value (`sub[0]`), and check if it's `'a'`:

```
if any(sub[0]=='a' for sub in l_list):
    print('Yes')
```

Using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) means it'll stop checking once it finds `'a'`.

Comment: I like this one the best because it is almost a literal translation of the question into code, and it should also be among the most efficient without literally writing a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will recursively check thru each sub table for the element no matter how dimensional your table is:

```
def find_reccursive(table, item_to_find):
    for el in table:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            return find_reccursive(el, item_to_find)
        else:
            return item_to_find in table
                
l_list = [['a', 2, True], ['b', 1, False], ['c', 5, True], ...]
if find_reccursive(l_list, 'a'):
    print("Found a")
```