# How to check if value "in" some collection *and* get it?

Tags: python, contains, membership, containment

I am thinking:

```
value = 3
s1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
s2 = {6,7,8,9,0}
s3 = {11,12,13,14,15}

if value in '..one of those sets..':
    '..give me that set..'
```

Is there an easier way to do this, apart from using `if`/`elif`?
Is there easier way to get `in` which set/list/tuple?

Comment: Why `if/elif`? Just one `if` is enough: `for s in (s1, s2, s3): if value in s: return s`

Comment: The boolean version of this: [Check if a sublist contains an item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728023/6045800) (i.e. only return ***if*** it exists, not in which one)

Comment: @Tomerikoo As that's a slightly different use case, maybe you could post an answer with your suggested solution? Whilst `next` on a generator (the answer posted so far) would work, your approach requires less advanced prior knowledge to understand.

Comment: Or, assuming `value` could be in more than one sets: `[s for s in (s1, s2, s3) if value in s]`, will return a list of all the sets containing `value` (if any). But depending on what you need, it may be better to have all the sets in a list or tuple, and return an index instead of the object itself

Comment: The "pythonic" way would be to use `try`/`except`. In other words, just try to get it and assume it's not there if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch the first set that contains the value:

```
value = 3
s1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
s2 = {6,7,8,9,0}
s3 = {11,12,13,14,15}

found = next(s for s in (s1, s2, s3) if value in s)
print(found)
```

**Output**

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need for multiple `if/elif` branches. That's a non-scalable approach for testing each sequence separately. But what if you add more sequences? You will need to change the code each time.

A simpler way is packing the sequences in a tuple and iterating over all of them and checking where the `value` is:

```py
for s in (s1, s2, s3):
    if value in s:
        print(s)
```

And this can be transformed to a list-comprehension if you expect the value to be in more than one sequence:

```py
sequences = [s for s in (s1, s2, s3) if value in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
# data
value = 3
s1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
s2 = {6,7,8,9,0}
s3 = {11,12,13,14,15}

if accepted_sets := [i for i in (s1, s2, s3) if value in i]:
    print(f'accepted sets: {accepted_sets}')
    print(f'first set: {accepted_sets[0]}')
```

output:

```py
accepted sets: [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
first set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

#### The `:=` defection operator

> ```
> if (data := server.get_data())['condition']:
>     ...
> ```
>
> ```
> data = server.get_data()
> if data['condition']:
>     ...
> ```
>
> These two codes work exactly the same. This way you do not need to request information from the server **twice**.